# Is there a more elegant way to wait for !=null in Dart in async methods?

Tags: dart, async-await

Currently I´m using this one in Dart as proposed by chatgpt ;-) but is there a better way to wait for not null? (PS: this is pure dart backend code, so Flutter Futurebuilder is not possible)

```
  String? command;

  Stream<({Message message})> detect(List<Message> messages) async* {
    while (command == null) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    }
  ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `command` into a [`Completer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) from [`dart:async`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/dart-async-library.html):

```dart
final Completer<String> command = Completer<String>();

Stream<({Message message})> detect(List<Message> messages) async* {
  await command.future;
  // ...
}
```

And when you want to assign a value to the completer you call:

```dart
command.complete(yourValue);
```

instead of doing

```dart
command = yourValue;
```